# JQuery Timepicker add to datepicker won't work

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I'm using these JS/CSS files, downloaded from `http://jqueryui.com/download/`

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="JS/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="JS/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.js"></script>
    <link href="JS/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

and

```
 <script src="http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
```

this is the first one which works:

```
 <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker();
        });
    </script>
```

and this one won't work for me:

```
   <script>          $(function () {
                  $('#timepicker').datetimepicker();
              }); </script>
```

The Datepicker is working fine, but nothing happens when I try to open the datetimepicker.

What am I missing?
Please note this is my first time using JQuery so it can be something very easy or very obvious. I just can't find it.

```
  <input type="text" id="datepicker" />  <input type="text" id="timepicker" />
```

Comment: is there any error in the console..

Comment: seems everything is okay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the issue by downloading the .js from the website I posted above. And now it works.
No clue why it didn't work with external JS file.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js"></script>
```

u need all the js files